# Java getting a .wav file to run inside a .jar

Tags: java

I am trying to get my .wav file to run from inside a .jar file once I have exported the program, and have researched extensively on the solution, but have found nothing that works.

Here is my current code:

```
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("soundfile.wav")));
        clip.start();
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Mind sharing your extensive research and what you have tried?

Comment: stuff like URL (which doesnt even slighty work) and other things you can easily find on stackoverflow, but nothing that acutally works

Comment: Are you sure you have researched this solution extensively? If you had, you would have run into loading files from an embedded resource.

Comment: And how does it "doesn't even slightly work"? You need to be more specific. Can you share the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A resource contained within the context of a `Jar` file is commonly known as an embedded resource.

These resources can not be accessed like normal file system resources (ie via the `File` class), instead, you need to use `Class#getResource`, which will return a `URL`, which can be, in you case, passed to `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream`

You could use something like...

```
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resources/soundfile.wav")));
```

In this example, the path is relative to the package location of the class instance.  That means if the resource is in another directory, you will need to to provide a full path to the resource